# regex inside ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

i have a rather simple regex expression (irony off) and ruby is treating it differently as expected

```
string = puts worksheet.sheet_data[5][10].value

string.split(/(?>(?>\([^()]*(?R)?[^()]*\))|(?>\[[^[\]]*(?R)?[^[\]]*\])|(?>{[^{}]*(?R)?[^{}]*})|(?>"[^"]*")|(?>[^(){}[\]", ]+))(?>[ ]*(?R))*/)
```

I already took out the (?R) and replaced it with \g<1> but after running it I still get the following error: *premature end of char-class:*

I got told that i need to escape some closing brackets because [^()] in ruby gets treated as if ] is still part of the set so i have to change it to [^()\]. I did all of that and my regex looks like this now:

```
string.split(/(?>(?>\([^()\]*\g<1>?[^()\]*\))|(?>\[[^[]\]*\g<1>?[^[]\]*])|(?>{[^{}\]*\g<1>?[^{}\]*})|(?>"[^"\]*")|(?>[^(){}[]", \]+))(?>[ \]*\g<1>)*/)
```

Its basically the same just that I removed previous \] escaping characters because ruby treats them as escaped anyway and added \ to closing brackets where there was none. Ruby still throws the same exception. I tried the regex previously on regexr.com so it must work.

EDIT:

the sample text is *attribute1, attribute2 (further specification,(even further specification, etc), another specification), attribute3, attribute4*

I should get
attribute1,
attribute2(further specification,(even further specification, etc), another specification),
attribute3,
attribute4

The commas inside parantheses should be ignored

Comment: Add some sample data for the regex...

Comment: i added a sample text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `\g<1>`, you need `\g<0>` since `\g<1>` recurses Capturing group #1 pattern, and `(?R)` recurses the whole regex pattern (and the whole pattern is Group 0).

Make sure you escape `[` and `]` inside character classes, they are special there in the Onigmo regex library.

You need

```
(?>(?>\([^()]*\g<0>?[^()]*\))|(?>\[[^\[\]]*\g<0>?[^\[\]]*\])|(?>{[^{}]*\g<0>?[^{}]*})|"[^"]*"|[^(){}\[\]", ]+)(?>[ ]*\g<0>)*
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/fn4CbIMYbcqWPL).